# auto populating cell values from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to auto populate cell values if a data validation says yes. Basically, if the contact address is the same as the site address, then it will pull the site address through to the contact address.

So far I have tried this code:

```
Sub PopulateSite()

Dim SiteName As Long
Dim Address1 As Long
Dim Address2 As Long
Dim Town As Long
Dim County As Long
Dim Postcode As Long
SiteName = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E7")
Address1 = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E17")
Address2 = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E19")
Town = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E21")
County = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E23")
Postcode = Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E25")

If Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("G29") = "Yes" Then
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E31") = SiteName
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E41") = Address1
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E43") = Address2
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E45") = Town
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E47") = County
Sheets("HV.Select Site Set Up").Range("E49") = Postcode
End If

End Sub
```

This, for some unknown reason, is not working. Please, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type declarations (I'm assuming based on variable names) are wrong.  I'm guessing that most of those values are `String` types (`Long` is used for numeric integers), so if you change your type declaration to `As String`, it should work as you need.

Comment: Thanks that works great. Do you know how i can make it run on a cell change?

Comment: @PeterMogford add the code to the `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_Calculate` method